# Create LXC Containers On Proxmox With KeyCtl and Nesting

Tags: ansible, lxc, proxmox

I have successfully created Ansible playbooks and roles to create and provision LXC containers on Proxmox. I'm now looking to use Ansible to run docker-compose files, ideally with the ability to spin up LXCs to run them on first.

I've created unprivileged containers successfully using Ansible, however before being able to use docker on the LXC I need to physically change the features of the container e.g

```
keyctl =1
nesting =1
```

Is anyone aware of doing this through an Ansible role ?

Answer (score 1):

see https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Linux_Container to have a line matching :

```
features: [fuse=<1|0>] [,keyctl=<1|0>] [,mount=<fstype;fstype;...>] [,nesting=<1|0>]
```

in your /etc/pve/lxc/VMID.conf